# Forcefully delete a field

Tags: entities

I created a custom field adding a .yml file in config/install. This field is listed under admin/reports/fields. Now I want to delete this field completely.

I tried uninstalling my custom module, but the field was still there.
I tried the following code, but it didn't work.

```
/**
 * Remove field_MY_FIELD_NAME.
 */
function MYMODULE_update_8001(&$sandbox) {
  $entityManager = \Drupal::service('entity.manager');
  $fields = $entityManager->getFieldDefinitions('node', 'MY_CONTENT_TYPE');
  if ($field = $fields['field_MY_FIELD_NAME']) {
    $field->delete();
  }
}
```

I ran the cron tasks after running the code, but it didn't help.

Is there a way to completely delete a field?